# Sketch the following set in the complex plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this set I need to sketch in the complex plane:

$S=\{ \in \mathbb{C} : \text{Im}[(2+)(3+5)]≥|−3+|≥|√5+2 | \wedge \text{Arg}(3−)≤\text{Arg}()≤\text{Arg}[ /2] \}$

So far I know that $\text{Im}[(2+)(3+5)]$ is $13$, $|−3+|$ is a circle where the centre is in $(3,1)$, $\text{Arg}(3-i)$ is $\tan^{-1}{\frac{-1}3}$ and $\text{Arg}[ 2]$ is $\tan \frac12$. The problem I have is with putting it altogether and sketching it.

Answer (score 1):

No, |z- 3+ i|= |z- (3- i)| is a circle where the center is at (3, -1).
13= |z- 3+ i| is a circle with center at (3, -1) and radius 13.   $13\le |z- 3+ i|$ region inside that circle.
$|sqrt{5}+ 2i|= \sqrt{5+ 4}= 3$ so $|z- 3+ i|\ge |\sqrt{5}+ 2i|$ is the disk outside the circle with center (3, -1) and radius 3.  I.e. $Im[(2+i)(3+ 5i)\ge |z-3+i|\ge |\sqrt{5}+ 2i|$ is the region between those two concentric circles.

Is that "$e i\pi/2$" or "$e^{i\pi/2}$?  The latter would make much more sense.

Comment: It is the latter, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to draw the permissible z-values in red in the enclosed picture. As already stated, the center of the circle is 3-i. the hatched area is not included in the solution.

[image]